# Should I be using a Standard Kalman Filter (KF) or an Extended Kalman Filter (EKF)?

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, gps, gyroscope, kalman-filter

So I am trying to implement a Kalman filter for an Inertial Measurement Unit (IMU) using an Arduino.

I have 4 sensors:

- GPS
- Accelerometer
- Gyroscope
- Magnetometer

To measure various vehicle properties such as velocity/acceleration/position/roll/yaw/pitch. I'm struggling to understand if I should be using a standard (KF) or EKF filter.

My guess is standard filter is fine as the sensor values have a linear relation to what I am trying to measure, but i'm not 100% sure on this.

Can anyone provide any insight? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe in the signal processing SE you can find the answers you need?

Comment: Depends on the available resources and required sampling time. EKF is better but more heavy.